# SQL GROUP BY error

Tags: sql

I am trying to retrieve result from a sql queries which returns duplicated userids from *Table1* into *Table3*.

Below is my sql statement:

```
INSERT INTO Table3(UserID, Name, Issue) 
   SELECT t1.UserID, t1.Name, 'Duplicated userid found in Table1' 
   FROM Table1 t1 
   GROUP BY t1.UserUD  
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

However, I received the following error after I tried to run it in my datasource:

> *Column 'Table1.Name' is invalid in the select statement list because it is not contained in either an aggregate functions or the GROUP BY
>   clause*

May I know where is my mistake?

Thank you

Comment: Try something like "GROUP BY t1.UserUD, t1.Name"

Comment: I think you need to add t1.Name to GROUP BY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Table3(UserID, Name, Issue) 
SELECT t1.UserID, t1.Name, 'Duplicated userid found in Table1' 
FROM Table1 t1 
GROUP BY t1.UserUD, t1.Name
HAVING COUNT(t1.UserID) > 1
```

You were missing the field in the group by

Answer (score 3):

you need to group by all the columns in your select that aren't in aggregate functions, i.e, in your case:

```
INSERT INTO Table3(UserID, Name, Issue)
SELECT t1.UserID, t1.Name, 'Duplicated userid found in Table1'
FROM Table1 t1 
GROUP BY t1.UserID, t1.Name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Or even, if you Name may not be duplicated as well:

```
INSERT INTO Table3(UserID, Name, Issue)
SELECT t1.UserID, MAX(t1.Name), 'Duplicated userid found in Table1'
FROM Table1 t1 
GROUP BY t1.UserID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

1. the group by t1.userUD and not ID seems suspicious
2. However, pretty sure you need to do group by t1.UserID, t1.Name. it won't change the logic of your query.